# Copy specific elements with childs of different XML files into output file and perserve overall structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My problem is that I have different XML files with identical structure and I want to extract certain elements of these input files and produce a new output document with the extracts which are combined.

So, let's get our hands dirty :-) (Example link below)

input1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<msg:Msg xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/2.0">
       <msg:preserve1>
          <msg:preserve2>
             <msg:preserve3>Preserve that</msg:preserve3>
          </msg:preserve2>
          <msg:Logon/>
       </msg:preserve1>
       <msg:Body>
          <msg:Req>
             <msg:Dta>
                <ResponseRowset xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/1.1"
                                xmlns="http://defaultnamespace">
                   <ResponseRow>
                      <ArticleNo>123</ArticleNo>
                      <List>02</List>
                      <Flag>2</Flag>
                   </ResponseRow>
                   <ResponseRow>
                      <ArticleNo>234</ArticleNo>
                      <List>02</List>
                      <Flag>3</Flag>
                   </ResponseRow>
                   <ResponseRow>
                      <ArticleNo>345</ArticleNo>
                      <List>03</List>
                      <Flag>3</Flag>
                   </ResponseRow>
                </ResponseRowset>
             </msg:Dta>
          </msg:Req>
       </msg:Body>
    </msg:Msg>
```

input2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<msg:Msg xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/2.0">
   <msg:preserve1>
      <msg:preserve2>
         <msg:preserve3>Preserve that</msg:preserve3>
      </msg:preserve2>
      <msg:Logon/>
   </msg:preserve1>
   <msg:Body>
      <msg:Req>
         <msg:Dta>
            <ResponseRowset xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/1.1"
                            xmlns="http://defaultnamespace">
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>3423</ArticleNo>
                  <List>03</List>
                  <Flag>3</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>234</ArticleNo>
                  <List>05</List>
                  <Flag>4</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>234</ArticleNo>
                  <List>01</List>
                  <Flag>4</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>456</ArticleNo>
                  <List>03</List>
                  <Flag>3</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
            </ResponseRowset>
         </msg:Dta>
      </msg:Req>
   </msg:Body>
</msg:Msg>
```

Now I want to copy all `<ResponseRow>` tags and their children into a new file if the `<ArticleNo>` tag contains one of the specified numbers.

Let's say I want to have all ResponseRow elements where the ArticleNo is either '234' or '456'

My expected result should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<msg:Msg xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/2.0">
   <msg:preserve1>
      <msg:preserve2>
         <msg:preserve3>Preserve that</msg:preserve3>
      </msg:preserve2>
      <msg:Logon/>
   </msg:preserve1>
   <msg:Body>
      <msg:Req>
         <msg:Dta>
            <ResponseRowset xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/1.1" xmlns="http://defaultnamespace">
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>234</ArticleNo>
                  <List>02</List>
                  <Flag>3</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>234</ArticleNo>
                  <List>05</List>
                  <Flag>4</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>456</ArticleNo>
                  <List>03</List>
                  <Flag>3</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>234</ArticleNo>
                  <List>05</List>
                  <Flag>4</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
               <ResponseRow>
                  <ArticleNo>456</ArticleNo>
                  <List>03</List>
                  <Flag>3</Flag>
               </ResponseRow>
            </ResponseRowset>
         </msg:Dta>
      </msg:Req>
   </msg:Body>
</msg:Msg>
```

It's working with following xsl file if I have everything in one file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:msg="http://some/msg/namespace/2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-16"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" xpath-default-namespace="http://defaultnamespace">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except ResponseRow[ArticleNo!='234' and ArticleNo!='456']"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I can't really get it to work with two or more input files. Here is the link to the "one-file" example: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBsK/33

What I don't like is the negating checks like *ResponseRow[ArticleNo!='234' and ArticleNo!='456']* as I will have a list of let's say 10 different article numbers to match but this is not my main focus.

Be aware that the namespaces look odd like this but I don't have influence on that as the files get generated by some vendor

It would be nice if you could help me out with that.

Comment: Look into [`document()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_doc.html) to parse from external files. As for the different article numbers, use application layer code like Java/Python/PHP and pass parameters into your XSLT in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The match on `*` looks odd to me, as for the second file and those article numbers, I would define a global parameter

```
<xsl:param name="articles-to-copy" as="xs:string*" select="'234', '456'"/>
```

and then match

```
<xsl:template match="ResponseRowset" xpath-default-namespace="http://defaultnamespace">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="(ResponseRow , doc('file2.xml')//ResponseRow)[ArticleNo = $articles-to-copy]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

of course accompanied by the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply which seems to do almost what i want. It runs through my files and selects all the ArticleNos i want, but only for one articleno. If I provide a list like you mentioned it gives me _Required cardinality of value of parameter $articles-to-copy is exactly one; supplied value has cardinality one or more_

Comment: @SebastianForza, sorry about that, it seems when I want a sequence type I always forget to add the asterisk to the type, at least in code snippets I don't test. Now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Martin Honnen who pointed out the way to go, the only not working was the parameter value.

So thank you again, and the final solution for me is:

```
<xsl:param name="articles-to-copy" select="('234', '456')" />

<xsl:variable name="pricelist01" select="document('input1.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="pricelist02" select="document('input2.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ResponseRowset" xpath-default-namespace="http://defaultnamespace">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="(ResponseRow, $pricelist01//ResponseRow, $pricelist02//ResponseRow)[StockCode=$articles-to-copy]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This is doing lookups in two other files. The only change i made was removing the *as="xs:string"* from the  tag. Looks really nice though :-)